# View taking too long to render when using relative path for image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, actionmailer

I have some views for email sending. When I use something like:

```
<%= image_tag('http://example.com/assets/image.png') %>
```

The email is taking this much to render:

```sh
Rendering mailers/user_mailer/verification_code_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
Rendered mailers/_header.html.erb (6.4ms)
Rendered mailers/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered mailers/_email_style.html.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered mailers/user_mailer/verification_code_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (17.3ms)
UserMailer#verification_code_email: processed outbound mail in 395.8ms
```

On the other hand, when I use a relative path like:

```
<%= image_tag('image.png') %>
```

The email is taking much longer to render:

```
Rendering mailers/user_mailer/verification_code_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
Rendered mailers/_header.html.erb (1222.9ms)
Rendered mailers/_footer.html.erb (3.0ms)
Rendered mailers/_email_style.html.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered mailers/user_mailer/verification_code_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1244.4ms)
UserMailer#verification_code_email: processed outbound mail in 1626.5ms
```

Everything else is the same in the application. Considering this, what might be the reason for such difference in rendering time? Is this expected?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the rails source code for image_tag. It eventually calls [`def asset_path`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3387676efdd03fd6e5b9a70b215ce02cdb1d4ee1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L183)

```
  def asset_path(source, options = {})
    raise ArgumentError, "nil is not a valid asset source" if source.nil?

    source = source.to_s
    return "" if source.blank?
    return source if URI_REGEXP.match?(source)

    tail, source = source[/([\?#].+)$/], source.sub(/([\?#].+)$/, "".freeze)

    if extname = compute_asset_extname(source, options)
      source = "#{source}#{extname}"
    end

    if source[0] != ?/
      if options[:skip_pipeline]
        source = public_compute_asset_path(source, options)
      else
        source = compute_asset_path(source, options)
      end
    end

    relative_url_root = defined?(config.relative_url_root) && config.relative_url_root
    if relative_url_root
      source = File.join(relative_url_root, source) unless source.starts_with?("#{relative_url_root}/")
    end

    if host = compute_asset_host(source, options)
      source = File.join(host, source)
    end

    "#{source}#{tail}"
  end
```

This function will quickly return if you pass a complete absolute url

```
return source if URI_REGEXP.match?(source)
```

If you look at the comments above the function definition they have also stated

> All fully qualified URLs are returned immediately

---

An absolute image path does not need to be modified by your rails server as the browser/email client will fetch it from the source directly. In case of a relative path, rails will need to form an absolute URL for it before it can be rendered.

<sub>Check their entire comment section [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3387676efdd03fd6e5b9a70b215ce02cdb1d4ee1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L152) - they explain in detail what will occur in each scenario.</sub>